# Shower leaks when valve is shut off but doesn't leak when the valve is slightly open

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

[image]Our contractor left in the middle of the shower job and we noticed that our shower leaks into the wall when the shower valve is completely shut off. When looking for the source of the leak, I noticed that the leak stops when the valve is slightly open.

The water leaks from the joint between the pipe in the wall and the shower head pipe. I noticed that the contractor did not use the PFTE tape when connecting the shower head pipe to the pipe in the wall.

I am not 100% sure about the model, but the valve looks like [this](http://www.moen.com/eva/oil-rubbed-bronze-posi-temp-r-shower-only/_/R-CONSUMER%3AT2132EPORB).

Do I need to replace the shower valve to fix the leak or is it because the contractor did not use the PFTE tape when connecting the shower head ?

Comment: The valve leaks or the connection between the valve and a pipe leaks?

Comment: The leak is in the connection between the pipe in the wall and the pipe to which the shower head is attached,

Comment: Please take a picture and circle the areas that leak.

Comment: It leaks from the circled area, into the shower wall.

Comment: That isn't where it is leaking from, that is where you notice the leaks.  You need to take each plate off to see where the water is coming from.  Let me know.  I doubt this is anything more than resecuring connections... but the one near the valve might include being able to access it from behind (or destroying tile).